# Google Drive API - query owned items

Tags: google-drive-api

I am working on a tool, and I want to query my own folders only. I can't formulate a query string that is accepted. I had read [Search for files](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/query-ref) page, and I am experimenting now with the API explorer.

1. String `mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'` yields folders. Good start.
2. `ownedByMe`, `ownedByMe = true` and `ownedByMe = false` all yield error 400 (*Invalid Value*), while when I use this field in the result set, it is shown.
3. `sharedWithMe`, `sharedWithMe = true` and `sharedWithMe != false` yields result, but interestingly I can't add this field to the result set and neither is it included in the field selector.
4. `sharedWithMe = false`, `not sharedWithMe`, `not sharedWithMe = true` and `sharedWithMe != true` all yield error 400

And I have tried some other less common syntaxes but now I am out of ideas :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "[my email] in owners" or "'me' in owners":

```
  var files = DriveApp.searchFolders("\(mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'\) and \('test@example.org' in owners\)");

  var files = DriveApp.searchFolders("\(mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'\) and \('me' in owners\)");
```

Comment: This requires an additional scope to get the email address of the user. Anyway, it works. I will accept this answer if no better is posted in a few days. Thank you.

Comment: If you expect multiple user contexts, use "me" instead.

  var files = DriveApp.searchFolders("\(mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder'\) and \('me' in owners\)");